# SmartGit Installation and Usage on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, ubuntu-12.04, smartgit

I have downloaded latest SmartGit installation and each time I want to use it I need to run script smartgit.sh from SmartGit bin directory, this process requires the same repository setup every time.

What it correct way of installing SmartGit on Ubuntu? Thus I can have normal icon and run the program from state of previous usage, without configuring repositories every time.

Thanks.

Comment: Which repository must be setup every time?

Comment: Local repository that I want to use.

Comment: SmartGit stores its settings in ~./smartgit/<version-number>. Here, projects.xml contains all pointers to your local Git repositories. I currently can't see why it should be necessary to re-setup them every time, unless you have changed "smartgit.home" somewhere in bin/smartgit.sh?

Comment: mstrap, `smartgit.sh` is the installer and the installer always prompts the user about finding or creating repositories.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> What it correct way of installing SmartGit on Ubuntu? Thus I can have
>   normal icon

In smartgit/bin folder,  there's a shell script waiting for you:  **add-menuitem.sh**.  It does just that.

Comment: What is the default location of this bin folder for ubuntu 14 users? I couldn't find it in /etc/ my ubuntu 14. My smartgit is working perfectly but I would like to try this setup also.

Answer (score 145):

You can add a PPA that provides a relatively current version of SmartGit(as well as SmartGitHg, the predecessor of SmartGit).

To add the PPA run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

To install `smartgit` (after adding the PPA) run:

```
sudo apt-get install smartgit
```

To install `smartgithg` (after adding the PPA) run:

```
sudo apt-get install smartgithg
```

This should add a menu option for you

For more information, see [Eugene San PPA](https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan/+archive/ppa).

> This repository contains collection of customized, updated, ported and backported packages for two last LTS releases and latest pre-LTS release

Comment: If anyone else finds this, make sure you do __sudo apt-get install smartgithg__ (don't forget `hg` on the end) this way you will get the latest version.

Comment: use this with caution as the ppa also holds new version of gnome 3 packages like gnome-session-data and may alter your gnome after a apt-get upgrade..

Comment: I added the PPA (copied and pasted the steps), but apt still can't find smartgit or smartgithg. I guess something's different in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: @MichaelScheper At this point(6 years after I originally posted this answer), It maybe simpler just get the .deb directly from the creators here: https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download/ I would strongly suggest reading the PPA description closely to determine if adding this PPA is appropriate for your needs. https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan/+archive/ppa YMMV

Comment: Yep, I ended up just downloading the .deb. Cheers.

Comment: Installs on arm64 but comes with x86/x64 native SWT.so. Any chance I can get an arm64 SWT library? Or the package can actually package a x86 and arm version?

Comment: The won't even work anymore, because the PPA is outdated. Use the .deb as in @Michele 's answer.

Answer (score 31):

Now on the [Smartgit webpage](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit) (I don't know since when) there is the possibility to download directly the .deb package. Once installed, it will upgrade automagically itself when a new version is released.

Answer (score 13):

Seems a bit too late, but there is a [PPA repository with SmartGit](https://launchpad.net/~eugenesan/+archive/ppa), enjoy! =)