# Linux manual program update

Tags: ubuntu, smartgit

I'm new Linux user and for git I'm use SmartGit product. So at the start of program it tells me that latest build cannot be fetched and I must get it from developers web site and install it manually. This program installed through 'apt-get install' command. So the question is, what is correct way to update SmartGit? Is there any way to do auto update? What is correct way to update any product on Ubuntu using terminal?

Comment: This answer to a similar question may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853924

Comment: thank you for answer, but your link it`s about installation. And I ask about update the program, which one installed already.

Comment: Please reread my answer: depending on the installation there are different ways of how the program can be updated. Definitely, *tar.gz* is the recommended package by *SmartGit developers*.

Comment: @snowhead: The canonical way of updating any program in your repos is `sudo apt-get update` `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Have you done this, and does it work?

Comment: @Bujiraso yes i did after your last comment, and at first look it is really helped, thank you

Answer (score -1):

For Linux, you have two options:

- `tar.gz` download, which is recommended. It's less Linux-style packaged, but portable and supports upgrading its installation directory.
- `Debian package (deb)` download which does not support installation directory upgrades (only minor patches).